# Hide orange plus ("Show Messages / Retry") in Mathematica

Tags: mathematica

If I accidently evaluate a text cell in Mathematica, a orange plus and an error message will appear. It is easy to delete the error messages, however I can't seem to find a way to hide the orange plus.

My current workaround is copying contents of the cell, deleting the cell and finally pasting it again.

Screenie:

[image]

Comment: I just noticed that you said "accidently evaluate a text cell" - I'm not sure that that is possible... since by default, text cells are not [evaluatable](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Evaluatable.html). Have you been using normal input cells for writing text instead of text cells? Maybe you should read the [Working with the Notebook Interface](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/WorkingWithTheNotebookInterfaceOverview.html) tutorial...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is controlled by a Cell option called `EmphasizeSyntaxErrors`. It can be removed by fixing the error and rerunning the cell, or manually using the cell expression or option inspector.

To view the expression of a cell, put the cursor in the cell or select its cell bracket and press Shift-Ctrl-E (also available under the Cell menu). Here's both the cell with an error and its cell expression:
[image: "Screenie"]

Then just delete the
`, EmphasizeSyntaxErrors->True` (don't forget the comma)
or change it to
`EmphasizeSyntaxErrors->False`

Alternatively, select the cell bracket and go to the [Option Inspector](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/menuitem/OptionInspector.html) (Shift-Ctrl-O or under the format menu) then under the "Editing Options" section you'll find the `EmphasizeSyntaxErrors` option that you can delete/set to default (on the left hand side) or set to False (on the right hand side):
[image: Option Inspector]